# Bracket syntax issue in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, regression

I'm trying to write a loop with will provide an r^2 value for each row. The issue I'm having is with how to format the [] or () to get a vector of the rows. I know it would be easier to call them by name, but this script will process different projects that won't all have the same number of columns - so hard coding the names isn't an option. The first column will always be wavelength and the remaining columns will always be the data points I want to use. To be clear, I want every column except wavelength to be included in the r^2 calculation.

The dataframe (statsDF) looks like this:

```
  Wavelength    Line_1    Line_2    Line_3    Line_4    Line_5    Line_6    Line_7
1       0400 0.4054731 0.3193632 0.2667026 0.8494675 0.2394639 0.2936054 0.2453124
2       0402 0.4048527 0.3195507 0.2693250 0.8664931 0.2380499 0.2931895 0.2437657
3       0404 0.4041760 0.3226145 0.2731347 0.8756971 0.2338797 0.2876017 0.2432391
4       0406 0.4079322 0.3264623 0.2750645 0.8770746 0.2273580 0.2866682 0.2476563
5       0408 0.4158769 0.3271127 0.2790707 0.8770176 0.2268334 0.2947697 0.2567014
```

My code looks like this:

```
rsq <- for (i in 1:nrow(statsDF)) {
    points <- as.numeric(statsDF([ , 2: ])) #The issue is here
    r2 <- summary(lm(Wavelength ~ points, data = statsDF))$r.squared
    print(r2)
  }
```

No matter what combination of () and [] I use it's giving me an error about unexpected symbols. I'm sure it's just something I'm overlooking, but I'm pretty new to R. Also I'm definitely open to sapply/etc. alternatives to the loop overall. Any ideas? Thanks!

**6/31 edit:**

I'm now trying the following script:

```
myR <- for (n in 1:nrow(statsDF)) {
   i <- cbind(2:ncol(statsDF))
   r2 <- summary(lm(statsDF[n,1] ~ as.matrix(statsDF[n , i]), options(na.action="na.omit")))$r.squared
   print(r2)
}
```

... That then produces this error:

```
Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : 
  variable 1 has no levels
```

I'm hoping there's just something obvious with this error that I'm not seeing. I've tried making both i and n `as.numeric`, `as.matrix`, and breaking them out into their own variables. I've also tried rewriting dataPoint to just be numbers and I've double checked that both dataPoint and Wavelength to factors - this did nothing.

As suggested I'm also trying this with a transposed version of the dataframe:

```
 dataPoint    0400        0402        0404        0406         408
1   Line_1  0.4054731   0.4048527   0.404176    0.4079322   0.4158769
2   Line_2  0.3193632   0.3195507   0.3226145   0.3264623   0.3271127
3   Line_3  0.2667026   0.269325    0.2731347   0.2750645   0.2790707
4   Line_4  0.8494675   0.8664931   0.8756971   0.8770746   0.8770176
5   Line_5  0.2394639   0.2380499   0.2338797   0.227358    0.2268334
```

With the following code:

```
myR2 <- for (n in 2:ncol(LongDF)) {
  r4 <- summary(lm(as.matrix(LongDF[1, ]) ~ as.matrix(LongDF[n, ]), 
options(na.action="na.exclude")))$r.squared 
  print(r4)
}
```

That then gets the following error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I've also started a Cross Validated question as suggested: (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474267/how-to-determine-statistical-significance-of-one-independent-variable-by-two-dep) - I think I worded my research questions better there.

**7/2 update:** I've given up trying to do statistics on this data set, instead relying on plotting the data and assuming people can visually understand which wavelengths are significant. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Comment: Have you tried `2:ncol(statsDF)` instead of just `2:`?

Comment: It sounds like you just want `lm(Wavelength ~ ., data = statsDF)` where `.` in the formula means "all the other columns." You don't need `points` here. Also, note that `for` loops always return NULL, they never return a value. So i'm not sure what you are doing with the `i` index It doesn't make sense to fit an `lm` model for each row. You have more variables than observations which doesn't make statistical sense.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to apply Python or Matlab-like syntax to R. Your loop doesn't use the value of `i` anywhere, so it seems a loop is unnecessary. As MrFlick says, a single call to `lm` is probably what you want. Also, you can't compute an R^2 value for a single set of observations (i.e., per row).

Comment: @MrFlick the `.` works great - but would you mind expanding on the `i` index? I'm trying to get this value for every row - if you have any alternatives I'd love to hear them

Comment: @jdobres To clarify the columns are different treatments - I want to know how much variation is explained by the treatment for each wavelength. I may be wording this poorly

Comment: @Mulligan You can't fit an `lm` model with more variables to estimate than the number of observations. What you are trying to do doesn't make mathematical sense. What do you want this r^2 value to represent exactly? What model are you trying to fit?

Comment: If you want to put each column into your `lm` model separately, you should start to fix your loop as `for (i in 2:ncol(statsDF))`  then you should pass the `i` as `lm(statsDF[,1] ~ statsDF[,i])`

Comment: Without getting too into it, we did different chemical treatments to a sample and took spectroscopy data after each time (treatment = line). I want to know statistically which wavelength this had an effect on. r^2 sounded the best for the job

Comment: I think you should get some statistical advice from [stats.se] first on how to properly analyze this data for your particular hypothesis.

Comment: @MrFlick Fair enough - I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like Wavelength and line number would be predictor variables (aka independent variables), with the values of this matrix as the predicted output (aka dependent variable)? Is that correct?

Comment: @jdobres Correct - the data in the matrix is their absorbance

Comment: @maydin I just tried your code - how would I get generate an r^2 for each wavelength (row) instead of treatment (column)? Thanks!

Comment: @Mulligan To build a model, basically speaking, you need dependent and independent variables. So if you look your data in row base, could you tell me what will be your dependent variable? Only the selected row's Wavelength? Since for every row there exists only one wavelength, how can you model such a thing? Modelling needs a bunch of data to detect a pattern inside it.

Comment: @maydin right - the dependent variables are the wavelength and treatments (lines) and the independent variables are their absorbances (the numbers that populate the bulk of the dataframe). For arguments sake, ignore everything in the dataframe except for one row. I just want to know what the r^2 value is between the treatments. Does that make more sense? I think I worded this question better on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474267/how-to-determine-statistical-significance-of-one-independent-variable-by-two-dep)